# on `Route` refresh getting issue with `angularjs`

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-routing

I have a `router` like this:

```
"user strict";

angular.module("ngTenderDocument", ["ngRoute", "ngResource", "docNaviDir"])

    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        $routeProvider.when('/', 
            {
                controller  : 'homeController',
                templateUrl : 'views/home.html'
            });
        $routeProvider.when('/chart', 
            {
                controller  : 'chartController',
                templateUrl : 'views/directiveViews/chart.html'
            })

    });
```

As well in my `home.html` page there is a link like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a id="first" href="#">First</a></li>
        <li><a id="prev" href="#">Previous</a></li>
        <li><input type="text" ng-model="page.count" name="" id=""></li>
        <li><a id="next" href="#">Next</a></li>
        <li><a id="last" href="#">Last</a></li>
        **<li><a href="/chart">Go to Chart Page</a></li>**
    </ul>
</nav>
```

when user click on the link, my page is loading exactly without issue. on click my bower location bar reads like :

```
http://localhost:3300/chart
```

But when i refresh the same location using my browser i am getting a error / message as :

```
Cannot GET /chart
```

how to solve this? I am using my server config like this:

```
var 
    connect = require('connect'),
    serveStatic = require('serve-static'),
    app = connect();

app.use(serveStatic('app')).listen(3300);
```

Where i need to do the changes to work `refresh`ing  a `router` url to work without any issue?

Any one help me?

By the way:

`http://localhost:3300/#/chart` //works fine and  redirects to `http://localhost:3300/chart`

Comment: You need to redirect all your traffic to your index route in NodeJS, but I don't have idea how to do it with your connect framework. You can check the next link http://compassinhand.com/2014/01/21/building-an-angularjs-app-using-node-js-and-expressjs/

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to configure serve-static.  Something like:

```
var serve = serveStatic('public/', {'index': ['home.html']})

app.use(serve).listen(3300);
```

Are you serving your files out of a `public` folder?

Comment: Tried, not working at all.. (even i am not getting the home page)

Comment: here that should get it...just set public/ to wherever your files are located